# highlight text and then send it to a pop up widget javascript

Tags: javascript, ember.js, widget, highlight

I'm trying to achieve something like this in EmberJS.

[image]

In the above image as you can see, user is able to highlight some text and upon `mouseup` event, the widget pops up with some icons. I want to achieve the same thing with the widget showing the highlighted text.

This is what I got so far:

```
export default Component.extend({
  classNames: ['widgetText'],
  didDrag: false,
  startDragPosition: null,
  endDragPosition: null,

  getSelected() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return '';
  },

  mouseUp(e) {
    if (this.get('startDragPosition') && this.get('didDrag')) {
      this.set('endDragPosition', { left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY });
      const selection = this.getSelected();
      console.log(selection);  //I'm able to print my selection, I want this to be sent to a widget and position the widget...?
    }
    this.setProperties({ didDrag: false, startDragPosition: null, endDragPosition: null });
  },

  mouseMove() {
    this.set('didDrag', true);
  },

  mouseDown(e) {
    this.set('startDragPosition', { left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY });
  },
```

I'm able to get the `highlighted text` and console log it, but I'm stuck on how to open up a widget and correctly position it in the middle somewhere and display the selected text inside that widget.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Ember Component that manage the popup as you want, if you can console.log the content of the highlighted text, you can lookup a variable like this:

```
isShowing():{
    this.togglePropety('isShowingComponent');
}
```

This will observe your variable `isShowingComponent`, so you can handle like this in your `.hbs`

```
{{#if isShowingComponent}}
    {{social-buttons close="isShowing"}}
{{/if}}
```

The only thing left it's the style for displayin like that, and if you want to send the text to do something with it you can do it like this:

```
{{#if isShowingComponent}}
    {{social-buttons close="isShowing" text='the text you already can console.log'}}
{{/if}}
```

Hope this helps you.